# Extracting values from last dimension of 3D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I'm trying to extract from a 3D matrix of values a 2d matrix were the last dimension has values from the last dimension of the 3d matrix. For example if 
P of dimensions [2,2,3] =

`[
  [[5, 1, 5], [9, 9, 4]], 
  [[0, 9, 8], [8, 6, 8]]
]`

what is the index matrix in order to get the out matrix
`[[1, 9],[0, 8]]` where 1 is the 2nd element of the first column of the first row, 9 is the 1st element of the first row second column, 0 is the 1st element of the second row first column and 8 is the 3rd element of the second row second column?
The idea is that, for each column I have k different scores. I want to retrieve for each column a different score for which I know the index.

I'm a bit confused with advanced indexing in Numpy and I'm not figuring it out by my self. Thanks!

Comment: How are you getting that pattern of `2nd element, 1st element, 1st element & 3rd element`? Or is it given as a separate indexing variable?

Comment: It can be another matrix that I use to index. The problem is given the matrix ``P`` and the matrix ``out`` what is the matrix ``I`` such that ``P[I] = out``?
I understand that ``I`` could be actually an expression for indexing or advanced indexing in numpy. What I mean is that I know which index I have to pick from P, what I don't know is how to index P in the correct way to have the right output.

Comment: @TommasoPasini that may not be easy. There a duplicate elements in `P`.

Comment: why is it a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming there's an indexing array to index into the last axis. Let's call it `idx`. For the given sample with the given text in the question, it would be -

```
idx = np.array([[1,0],[0,2]])
```

Specifically, this was extracted from the quoted text :

> 1 is the **2nd element** of the first column of the first row, 9 is
>   the **1st element** of the first row second column, 0 is the **1st
>   element** of the second row first column and 8 is the **3rd element**
>   of the second row second column

To solve, we will use open grid with `np.ogrid` to index into the first two axes of the input array -

```
m,n = idx.shape
I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
out = A[I,J,idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [57]: A
Out[57]: 
array([[[5, 1, 5],
        [9, 9, 4]],

       [[0, 9, 8],
        [8, 6, 8]]])

In [59]: idx = np.array([[1,0],[0,2]])

In [60]: m,n = idx.shape

In [61]: I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]

In [62]: A[I,J,idx]
Out[62]: 
array([[1, 9],
       [0, 8]])
```

Comment: perfect! I already tried this way before and I don't know why it didn't work probably I missed something. Thank you very much! Could you explain why as idx I need a 2 dimensional matrix? Thanks